# ADF: Load javascript resources conditionally

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have following line on my page:

```
<af:resource type="javascript" source="JS/google.projected.overlay.js"/>
```

I need this resource to be loaded on particular conditions. Condition can be calculated via EL-expression. So I tried:

```
<af:panelGroupLayout visible="false" rendered="#{Condition}" id="pgl1">
    <af:resource type="javascript" source="JS/google.projected.overlay.js"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

But it does not work. Script tag is always rendered on the page in head section despite of my conditions.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the af:resource tag for this as the doc says

> The resource is added to the af:document component to be included when
>   the document is rendered.

so the rendered condition don't come to play here. 
You may go and check out this [ADF JavaScript Partitioning](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://adfproject.googlecode.com/files/ADF%2520JavaScript%2520Partitioning.pdf&ei=AGNQUNe6C6i-0QX6qoDYBg&usg=AFQjCNHQi0WAvIpJxQQLWEslzrzqBY75Uw&sig2=cC-5mYMf0lP8Vy6EO7CYng) or [A.9 Using JavaScript Library Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/web.1111/b31973/ap_config.htm#BABCJIDJ) or you can pipe the script code into the page from a bean method.
If you evaluate the condition in a bean method you can add the script from the bean method to the page just when it's needed. For this your can use the ExtendedRenderKitService like

```
    // queue JavaScript into the page
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExtendedRenderKitService erks =
    Service.getService(context.getRenderKit(), ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
    String script = "YOUR CODE HERE";
    erks.addScript(context, script);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification with docs! Executing script via renderKit does not suite my usecase. I'm interesting in creating my own js-partition. Could you please give more guidelines where to digg how to link my custom partiotion to something on a page?

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested it, but what if you change rendered="#{Condition}" to rendered="${Condition}" for eager EL resolving?

Given the scrip is cached on the browser once loaded, does it really make a difference if it is conditional or not?

Frank

Comment: Its not suitable for my usecase. What want to archive - is browser not to download/cash my script. And as far as I know EL expressions does not accepts ${} syntax. "JSF EL expressions use the syntax #{expr}" -this is quote from docs http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/2update1/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html